# HTML element is cut off when exceeding right boundary on screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have a website where I use a table to display some data. The issue is that when I view the website on smaller screens, the table is cut off and not all of the content is displayed. You can see below that despite me scrolling all the way to the right, the right most field is only barely visible and cut off by the screen.

I seem to partly be able to fix this by the width css parameter in root but if I set width too high, is just adds unnecessary right margin.

```
import React  from 'react';
import {ListUsersTableRow} from "./listUserTableRow";
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Table, { TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from 'material-ui/Table';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - 140px)`,
    },
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },
});

export const ListUsersTable = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Edit</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Full name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Username</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Company</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Contact Number</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Role</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.users.map(user => <ListUsersTableRow key={user.id} {...user} toggleEdit={props.toggleEdit}/>)}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  )
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ListUsersTable);
```

[image: Screenshot of website]

Comment: Is the menu on the left an off-canvas menu? seems like the open menu pushes the page out of the view. (If it is, it is expected behaviour)

Comment: Yep, it does push the content out. However, if I set width to 100%-240px (width of drawer) I get a large gap at the right

Comment: Are there any CSS rules at the menu that affect body or some wrapping element of the content? It might be adding padding-left. Never used 100%-xxx calculations before thus don't know exactly if it should work.

Comment: I think it's because you have a `table{minWidth: 700}`,regardless it'll be better if you post a working snippet

Comment: sure thing, could you point me in the direction of a snippet tool that supports 3rd party npm packages like material design?

Answer (score 0):

min-width is causing your table to be *at least* as wide as 700.

Try something simple like width: 100%;

If width:100%; messes up your side menu, you may want to consider setting the width of the menu to something like 30% instead of, say, 240px. With your menu taking up 30% of the page, and your table taking up the other 70%, things *should* fit a little better.

Rough guess without working example, though.

Comment: Thanks, a 30% width for the menu might look funny on larger screens. Is there any good tool for showing a working example in the browser?

Comment: I personally just use Chrome Dev Tools. If you right click your page, click "Inspect" on the element you're looking to modify. Your code should show up under "Elements". You can't make permanent code changes here, but you can tamper with existing code and see how things would fit. For example, you should be able to right click, inspect your table, and then input your dimensions with immediate feedback on the web page